# sabre file manager file path define value php

Tags: php, filepath, sabre

I using sabre file manager. I write dynamic file path but upload not work.

write like this its not working;

```
define('sb_file_path', '../upload/'.$_SESSION['url']);
```

I tried this codes

```
define('sb_file_path', '../upload/'.$_SESSION['url']); 
define('sb_file_path', '../upload/'.$_SESSION['url'].'/');
```

but manually write like this upload successful.

```
define('sb_file_path', '../upload/test');
```

how to working with dynamic value?? thanks.

Comment: please show us If you add `var_dump($_SESSION['url']);`  what appears to you?

Comment: Can you confirm that `$_SESSION['url']` has data? Generally, the session variable is not very reliable and definitely should NOT be relied on to pass data between pages. Instead, it is much more reliable to save them in DB.

Comment: and don't forget  bro to add `session_start()` in the first of script, then  don't forget to save some data in `$_SESSION['url']`

Comment: session_start() at the beginning of the page. $_SESSION['url'] output = Array([url] => test).